# Finding field and contour families that would produce zero integrals at every point

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

**Context:**

In Cartesian coordinates, consider a vector field $\boldsymbol{f}=\boldsymbol{f}(x,y)$ defined over some domain $\Omega$ in the $xy$ plane. Taking a closed contour $\Gamma$ that encloses surface area $A$ at any point inside the same domain ($\Omega$), then we can define the two integrals

$$I_{1}=\int_{\Gamma}\boldsymbol{f}\cdot\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}dl,$$
$$I_{2}=\int_{\Gamma}\boldsymbol{f}\cdot\boldsymbol{dl},$$

where $dl$ is the length element along the contour, $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector normal (perpendicular) to the element $dl$ at each point in the plane, and bold symbols represent vector quantities.

To make $I_{2}=0$, we can choose the contour $\Gamma$ shape to be orthogonal to the field flowlines at each point, whereas to make $I_{1}=0$, we choose them to be parallel at each point.  For example, if the field is generated radially from a point source in the plane, we can choose the contour shapes to be concentric circles around the source point, so that these circles will always cross the radial field lines perpendicularly and give $I_{2}=0$. Or if the field is circular flow, we can choose the contour to also be circular, and thus get $I_{1}=0$. These examples should work regardless of how large/small the enclosed area $A$ is taken.

**The question:**

Is there any nontrivial example of a family of fields and contour shapes that we can choose that will give us $I_{1}=0$ or $I_{2}=0$ **at every point** (not necessarily concentric) and for **any size** of enclosed area $A$ (including when $A\rightarrow0 $) in the domain of the problem? Can you given any practical examples of scenarios that could lead to this?

And if this is impossible to satisfy at every point, is there a theorem/proof about this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't know Green's Theorem (or, more generally, Stokes's Theorem and Gauss's Theorem, also called the Divergence Theorem). Assuming your vector field is continuously differentiable, you certainly can't even accomplish your goal for *one* point unless you have strong conditions on $\text{div}\, \boldsymbol f$ and $\text{curl}\,\boldsymbol f$. To get $I_1=0$ in a non-instantaneous fashion, you'll need $\text{div}\, \boldsymbol f=0$ on a region containing your point, and, likewise, to get $I_2=0$  you'll need $\text{curl}\,\boldsymbol f = \mathbf 0$ on a region. The latter happens, in particular, for conservative force fields, i.e., when $\boldsymbol f = \nabla\phi$ for some function $\phi$. [Geometrically, you can't get curves as you described unless the field flowlines form closed curves; usually that won't happen. Nor, in general, will the orthogonal trajectories of the field lines form closed curves. The examples you have in your mind are special cases indeed.]

Side remark:  You can get vanishing of *both* $I_1$ and $I_2$ when $\boldsymbol f = \nabla\phi$ and $\phi$ is harmonic on your region in the plane. Then both the curl and divergence will vanish.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know Stokes' and Divergence theorems, and I understand that $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ can be described in terms of curl and div. But what I was interested in knowing was whether it can be possible to make the integrals vanish by some appropriate choise of contour shapes, rather than by making the integrand itself vanish (as in curl $f$=0 or div $f$=0). Imagine a 2D domain (like a planar cavity) where the wave equation is to be solved subject to the boundary conditions at the domain edges, and it gave eigenfunctions as solutions. Now let $f$ be some linear...

Comment: (2/2)...combination of these solutions, taken as our integrand. Then can one find families of contours over which the integrals will vanish at every point (even when the contours become very small and basically defining points)? Because then the integrand will also need to vanish at every point in the domain and this may have interesting consequences...

Comment: OK, well, your idea was to make the line integral integrand vanish at every point. As I pointed out, that surely can't happen with closed curves, in general. So both of us need to pick shapes to make the integral of div/curl vanish, in general (if there is any symmetry or anti-symmetry at all).

Comment: So, if I've from physical facts the following relation held true:$\int_{\sigma\Omega}f\cdot \hat{n} dl=0$ (ie. at the domain boundary, assuming simple domain, like a square or disk) And I wish to do a similar integral on interior regions of arbitrary shape,to see if it can vanish there too. How would you suggest I do it? My initial idea was to try to find contours similar in shape to the outter boundary of the domain, then start shrinking them slowly and see if the integrals will still vanish. Then I became interested in knowing if there exist fields or contours that will make it 0 everywhere.

Comment: Let's talk about a specific $\boldsymbol f$.

Comment: OK. $f(x,y): \nabla^{2}f+k^{2}f=0$ on the square domain from $(0,0)$ to $(a,a)$, with boundary forcing $f$ to have zero tangent component on boundary. An example solution would be $f(x,y)=\hat{i}\sin(mky)+\hat{j}\sin(nkx)$, with $k=\pi/a$ and $m,n$ are integers.

Comment: So for that, the divergence vanishes identically, so the flux integrals will always vanish. For the work integrals, you see that $\text{curl} = n\cos nx-m\cos my$, so you can use symmetry to pick regions "centered" on $y=x$ (or symmetric about $\pi/2$ appropriately) to make those integrals vanish.

Comment: But that would restrict us to prove vanishing only for points on those symmetry lines, not all the domain points, right?  Could this be generalised into some theorem to tell which types of field integrals can/cannot be made to vanish like this everywhere using appropriate small regions to intergate over?

Comment: In particular, if either the divergence or the curl has constant sign near a point, no closed curve near that point could work.

Comment: I see. You mean the neighbourhood will need to be balanced as to cancel out under integration. Well, then, if I understand this correctly, and barring the special case of zero curl and/or zero divergence everywhere, and assuming that our integrals are over infinitesimally small regions centred at arbitrary points in the plane, then it would be probably impossible to find any type of field that gives 0 integrals here. Right? Because that would imply an inifnitely oscillating field even at the finest resolution, which would not be integrable, right?

Comment: Nothing about oscillation. If the function is both positive and negative near the point, you can choose regions to make the net integral 0.

Comment: Yes, but for the integral to vanish everywhere, if integrand was positive and negative near one point, then we moved into another nearby point, then it must flip again to have positive and negative values near the new point, and so on, as we move from point to point in the domain. So, for it to vanish at all these points, it has to keep flipping its sign, which is more or less oscillatory behaviour (regardless of magintude). Isn't it?